# Is there a 2d for-loop of doing this layout ? Like a shortcut

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox, quasar

[image]

```
          //1st column
                 <div class="container-1">
                    <div v-for = "item2 in arrayDivs1" class="card-1" > 

                            <q-card-main    >
                                <div  style="background">
                                    <!--<img src="/statics/imgs/serenitea.jpg">-->

                                    <h2>{{item2.price}}</h2>
                                    <!--<q-card-actions>
                                        <q-btn flat label="7:30PM" />
                                    </q-card-actions>  -->
                                </div>
                            </q-card-main>
                      </div>
                  </div>
          //2nd column
                   <div class="container-1">
                    <div v-for = "item2 in arrayDivs1" class="card-1" > 

                            <q-card-main    >
                                <div  style="background">
                                    <!--<img src="/statics/imgs/serenitea.jpg">-->

                                    <h2>{{item2.price}}</h2>
                                    <!--<q-card-actions>
                                        <q-btn flat label="7:30PM" />
                                    </q-card-actions>  -->
                                </div>
                            </q-card-main>
                      </div>
                 </div>
         //3rd column
                    <div class="container-1">
                    <div v-for = "item2 in arrayDivs1" class="card-1" > 

                            <q-card-main    >
                                <div  style="background">
                                    <!--<img src="/statics/imgs/serenitea.jpg">-->

                                    <h2>{{item2.price}}</h2>
                                    <!--<q-card-actions>
                                        <q-btn flat label="7:30PM" />
                                    </q-card-actions>  -->
                                </div>
                            </q-card-main>
                      </div>
                 </div>
     //.. copy paste up to 5th column
```

What's a more efficient way of writing this? instead of writing the same HTML/CSS block 5 times repeatedly?

Is there a 2d for-loop we can do to create this grid layout with less code? like:

```
 for(var i =0;i<3; i++){
       for(var j =0;j<3; j++){
              //create your 2d cards here
       }
  }
```

expected outcome:
[image]

Comment: `v-for` twice? What does the data structure look like? You can use a [range v-for](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range) if you just want to repeat X number of columns: `v-for='n in 5'`.

Comment: Add all the cards to the same container, and arrange the grid layout using CSS Grid; which should allows you to iterate over just the cards, rather than the columns and cards. But, as Bert suggests, without seeing your structure it's very hard to say for certain what might/could work.

Comment: Something like this possibly https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GGbzQK

Comment: @Bert thanks Bert, post that as answer..

Comment: @David Thomas edited the question to show my structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to repeat the data you have N times. That being the case, you could use a [range v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range) to repeat the columns.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    arrayDivs: [0,200,400]
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: .25em;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class= "col" v-for="n in 5">
    <div class="box" v-for="div in arrayDivs">{{div}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks bert, can you modify it a lil like this https://imgur.com/a/pyDxg7C ? that's the structure. I spent more than an hour trying to get my head around this. thanks very much.

Comment: @noogui just add `<div class= "row">
    <div class="box" v-for="div in arrayDivs">{{div}}</div>
  </div>`. then uses css `.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}`